# How to iterate groupby inside groupby with different variables in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a huge dataset of the temperature of each hour on a day for 50+ cities. I want to get dataframe of max,min, and average tempearture date-wise for each city. For eg Dataset contains

City    Date    Time    Temperature

I want dataframe for each city that contains Max, min, and average temperature for every day (like city1_df, city2_df) etc.. I have tried groupby function inside groupby, but does not know how to iterate the process with different variable names.

```
cities=df.groupby('City')
city1=cities.get_group('New York')

city1_max=city1.groupby('Date').max()
city1_min=city1.groupby('Date').min()
city1_avg=city1.groupby('Date').mean()

city1_max=city1_max.drop(columns=['City','Time'])
city1_min=city1_min.drop(columns=['City','Time'])

city1_max=city1_max.rename(columns={'Temperature':'Max Temp'})
city1_min=city1_min.rename(columns={'Temperature':'Min Temp'})
city1_avg=city1_avg.rename(columns={'Temperature':'Avg Temp'})

city1_df=pd.concat(['city1_max','city1_min','city1_avg'], axis=1)
```

How can I automate this process through various cities?

Comment: Please provide a sample of the input dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can groupby `City` and `Date` directly, and apply `min`, `max` and `mean` function on `Temperature` column.

Then use [pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html#pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values) to return all cities and retrieve them into list.

```py
df_ = df.groupby(['City', 'Date'])['Temperature'].agg(['min', 'max', 'mean']).set_axis(['Min Temp', 'Max Temp', 'Mean Temp'], axis=1)

dfs = [df_.loc[city] for city in df_.index.get_level_values(0)]
```